# Set expandable a MenuLinkTreeElement programatically

Tags: drupal-9

When loading a menuTree a MenuLinkTreeElement instance's subtree is empty when this instance is not expanded.
How to set its expanded property to 1 programmatically ?

Example:

```
$parameters = $menu_link_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('admin');
$tree = $menu_link_tree->load('admin', $parameters);
$admin_link = reset($tree);
dpm($admin_link);

return

Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTreeElement {#242 ▼
  +link: Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault {#261 ▶}
  +subtree: []
  +depth: 1
  +hasChildren: true
  +inActiveTrail: false
  +access: null
  +options: []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following line:

```
$parameters->expandedParents = [];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).